# How to Install CakePHP Console?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.8 project hosted on github: https://github.com/paultrimor/pecunia

1. I can successfully clone the project, run `composer install` & configure `app.php` to have the application run.
2. However; the installation does not create a `/bin` directory, meaning that I cannot use the Console/Shell.

**I am looking to install the Console on an existing CakePHP project**

I receive the following message when I win `composer install` and `composer create-project --prefer-source``

```
> App\Console\Installer::postInstall
Set Folder Permissions ? (Default to Y) [Y,n]? n
Updated Security.salt value in config/app.php
> App\Console\Installer::postInstall
Set Folder Permissions ? (Default to Y) [Y,n]? n
No Security.salt placeholder to replace.
```

The first command replaces the "**SALT**" string to an actual hash in `app.php`; But, the second command tries to do the same thing, which it cannot.

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an error, it's just a warning that it looked for the placeholder and didn't find it. Which is to be expected, because it was already replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already solved it looking at your repo, but the `bin/` folder should be part of your repository. It will not be created with a `composer install` or `composer update` command.

If you create a new project using `composer create-project cakephp/app --prefer-dist` the `bin/` executables will be placed. If you don't explicitly ignore it in `.gitignore` it will be available to all developers.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : check PHP Version
`php -v`
Step 2: Install Composer
step 3: create a new CakePHP application using composer.
`composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app projectname`

while installing it asking permission for folder just give `yes`

`Set Folder Permissions ? (Default to Y) [Y,n]?  Y`

it will work.